# toggle function to shown two pandastable dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, tkinter, toggle

Dears,

during the last step of a project, I'm facing a problem with appearing tables in the way I'm looking for.
that I need to show data on the pandastable based on a condition if the number of rows was less than 35 row, the data has to show normally and that work with me properly, else the data has to be divided by two data frames then shown the first 35 rows and when we press on key switched to show the second one

here is my try :

```
countrow = df4[df4.columns[5]].count() 
print(countrow)
s=34
if countrow > s:
    
    dfst = df4.iloc[:35,:]
    dfnd = df4.iloc[35:,:]
    pt=Table(frame,dataframe=dfst)
    pt.show(dfst)
    exec(open("color.py").read())
    print("red")
    if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
        
        pt=Table(frame,dataframe=dfnd)
        pt.show(dfnd)
        exec(open("color.py").read())
    else :
        pass
else :
    pt=Table(frame,dataframe=df4)
    pt.show(df4)
    exec(open("color.py").read())


pt.resizeColumn(0 ,720) 
pt.redraw()
```

your support and remarks or advice and suggestion, please.

**Thank you in advance!**

Comment: What is your main problem? Is the code giving an error or just not working as expected? Also, why are you creating a variable s? If you need variable s, then while slicing use s + 1, You can change the value easily from 1 place.

Comment: You should also close the files you have opened which you have not done. Simply use the `with` statement to do so. Also, there is no need to use `exec` to open the files, it can be done with regular python code.

Comment: When I press key "q" not switching to show the 2nd data frame 
and  about s variable just to compare